# Is it possible so send just a part of an object by angular resource?

Tags: angularjs

I have a resource where the get is receiving an object like `{metadata : {}, data : {}}`. But when I save, I just want to send the data and not metadata.

```
    .factory("$profile", function($resource) {
        return $resource("service/profile/:profileid");
    })
    .controller('ProfileController', function($scope, $routeParams, $profile) {
        $scope.profile = new $profile();
        $scope.doSave = function() {

            // need to send profile.data only               << ----------

            $scope.profile.$save($routeParams, function(data) {
                console.log("saved profile");
            });
        }
```

What I have done right now is the following:

```
    .controller('ProfileController', function($scope, $routeParams, $profile) {
        $scope.profile = new $profile();
        $scope.doSave = function() {

            $scope.profile.data.$save = $scope.profile.$save;

            $scope.profile.data.$save($routeParams, function(data) {
                console.log("saved profile");
            });
        }
```

This works but I am sure there is a much cleaner way to do what I need to do. Ideally I would tell the resource to look for a data property on "save".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. The properties you need are 'transformResponse' (on GET) and 'transformRequest' (on Post).

```
.factory("$profile", function($resource) {
  return $resource("service/profile/:profileid",
    {},
    {
      get: {
        method: 'GET',
        transformResponse: function(response, headers){
          return response.data;
        }
      },
      post: {
        method: 'POST',
        transformRequest: function (request, headers) {
            var result = request.data; // << This line might not be exactly what you need.
            return result;
        }
      }
    });
})
```

I actually suspect that the transformRequest part isn't needed at all (but you did ask for it).

```
$scope.profile.$save($routeParams, function(data) {
  console.log("saved profile");
});
```

Comment: actually I need the post example, so what I did is: `save : {
                    method: 'POST',
                    transformRequest: function (request, headers) {
                        var result = request.data;
                        return result;
                    }
                }` but this sends me just a string  [Object object]. I think it is save to use JSON.stringify but I feel like this is wrong.

Comment: I've seen examples where people have used either encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data)) or $.param(data)
It seems it is necessary when transforming the request